# Getting an error "A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `payload`. Value: " in react-redux

Tags: react-redux

[image]I wrote a function in add user and remove user on react-redux. But i getting error on this function

user Slice.js in redux

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: {
      id: "",
      name: "",
      email: "",
    },
  },
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
    },
    removeUser: (state) => {
      state.users = "";
    },
  },
});

export const { addUser, removeUser } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

The remove user funcion is returning a empty string. on the screen value is empty.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeUser } from "../Slices/userSlice";
import {} from "react-redux";

const User = () => {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users.users);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(users);

  const removeuser = (state) => {
    dispatch(removeUser(state));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{users.id}</h1>
      <h2>{users.name}</h2>
      <h3>{users.email}</h3>

      <button type="" onClick={removeuser}>
        Remove User
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default User;
```

what the solution of this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am seeing in your error message is that you are passing a React event in your action payload.

Why is this happening?  An `onClick` prop is a function which gets called with the click event as its argument.

```
<button type="" onClick={removeuser}>
```

So the argument of `removeuser` needs to be `(event) => {`.  Or if you don't need to access the event then you can use `() => {`.  There is no scenario in which a `state` variable makes sense as an argument.

---

When you call a Redux Toolkit action creator function, the argument that you pass to the function will become the `action.payload`.

With the way that your slice is set up now, the `removeUser` reducer does not use the `action.payload` so it does not need an argument.  You just call `dispatch(removerUser())`.

```
const onClickRemove = () => {
    dispatch(removeUser());
};

/* ... */
<button onClick={onClickRemove}>
```

or

```
<button onClick={() => dispatch(removeUser())}>
```

---

Does you app have more than one user?  As you begin to understand things more, your `userSlice` will probably evolve.  You may end up with an array of users, in which case your `removeUser` action will need to know which user to remove.

Something like:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: {
    users: []
  },
  reducers: {
    // Payload is an array of user objects.
    setAllUsers: (state, action) => {
      state.users = action.payload;
    },
    // Payload is a single user object.
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      state.users.push(action.payload);
    },
    // Payload is the id of the user to remove.
    removeUser: (state, action) => {
      state.users = state.users.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload);
    },
  },
});

export const { setAllUsers, addUser, removeUser } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { removeUser } from "../Slices/userSlice";

const UsersList = () => {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users.users);
  console.log(users);

  return (
    <div>
       {users.map(user => (
          <UserListItem key={user.id} user={user}/>
       ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const UserListItem = ({ user }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{user.id}</h1>
      <h2>{user.name}</h2>
      <h3>{user.email}</h3>

      <button onClick={() => dispatch(removeUser(user.id))}>
        Remove User
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UsersList;
```